# AWS Python Lambda with Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to connect to an *Oracle db* from `AWS Lambda` using python. I managed to package cx_Oracle but the environment does not find the dependencies.

I had zipped the content, which contained `cx_Oracle.so` and `cx_Oracle-5.2.1-py2.7.egg-info` (created on 64bit AWX Linux). I also added the files from `instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip` into local/lib in that zip file.

The error I get is

```
import cx_Oracle

ImportError: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I dynamically change environment variables in python like so:

```
oracledir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'local', 'lib')
libdir = os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] + ":" + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'local', 'lib')

command = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH={} ORACLE_HOME={} python OracleWorker.py "{}"'.format(libdir, oracledir, args)
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

OracleWorker.py starts with `import cx_Oracle`

Comment: Its not worth asking the same question over - please edit your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715080/oracle-driver-for-aws-python-lambda) question

Comment: The previous question was regarding a tutorial which was against the policy. The answer you provided was the generic aws tutorial which did not help on this case. The question above details the exact steps I have taken and results I am getting. Please again note that I did follow that tutorial as a first step without results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. Added all dependencies by running 
    `ldd cx_Oracle.so| grep "=> /" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I '{}' cp -v '{}' /destination`
Added all those files in destination to lib folder in lambda zip

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I am getting this error  """DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: \"libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\"""  I have put all the files in of instantclient_12_12 into lib folder and index.py along with cx_Oracle at the same level as lib. Can you please share your zip or the directory structure. Thank you