# AWS Python Lambda with Oracle - OID Generation Failed even after adding HOSTALIASES

Tags: python, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to *oracle* on *rds* using *lambda* with *python* using *cx_oracle package* but i get:

> ORA-21561: OID generation failed: DatabaseError.

Even after adding file */tmp/HOSTALIASES* with the *lambda-server-name* `localhost`. Also added `HOSTALIASES` to *lambda environment variables*. Referd from: [AWS Python Lambda with Oracle - OID Generation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201869/aws-python-lambda-with-oracle-oid-generation-failed).

How to resolve this OID generation problem in *aws lambda*

Here is my code

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
import sys
import time

# sys.path.append('lib')
# os.environ['ORACLE_SID'] = 'DEVDB'


with open('/tmp/HOSTALIASES', 'w') as hosts_file:
    hosts_file.write('{} localhost\n'.format(os.uname()[1]))

def orcl_fetch_records(event, context):
    # print (sys.path)
    # print (os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
    # print (os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'])

    # print (os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'])
    # print (sys.path)
    print (os.environ['HOSTALIASES'])
    with open('/tmp/HOSTALIASES', 'r') as hosts_file:
        print hosts_file.read()
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("aws-rds-oracle-server-name", "1521", "SID")
    print (dsn)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password", dsn)
    print ("Oracle DB version = " + conn.version)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('select * from lambda_test')
    for result in cur:
        print (result)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Output:

> ORA-21561: OID generation failed: DatabaseError Traceback (most recent
>   call last): File "/var/task/orcl_fetch_function.py", line 25, in
>   orcl_fetch_records conn = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password",
>   dsn) DatabaseError: ORA-21561: OID generation failed

Comment: Welcome to SO. Hoora for finishing the tour and nice question and shown error code (tip: try using ">" and you get yourself a yellow box as background for the trackback). No further comments from review side.  Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That error is generally due to the fact that your host name cannot be determined. This post may be of help: https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2015/10/connecting-to-oracle-instance-in-aws-rds/

Comment: In AWS Lambda I don't have write access to etc/hosts file. So i have set the hosts by adding HOSTALIASES file and setting the values in HOSTALIASES file as "host-name localhost" . I have also tried the format from the URL you have given "127.0.0.1 host-name localhost". It still throws same OID generation error.

Comment: Is the client the same as the server? Or are you using different machines?

Comment: I trying to connect to rds oracle DB on same aws vpc which lambda function is executing.

Comment: So what is the value of your /tmp/HOSTALIASES? And the value of the environment variable HOSTALIASES? Everything I've seen suggests this should work. What version of cx_Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and found that the HOSTALIASES mechanism requires working DNS.  If your Lambda function is VPC attached, you must allow outbound DNS to either Amazon VPC DNS or your own internal DNS server if you have one.