# AWS Nodejs Lambda query On prem Oracle 11g RAC

Tags: node.js, oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, aws-lambda

We have this unique integration which we are working out from AWS Lambda Function -> Oracle 11g RAC(On Prem).

We have chosen AWS Lambda with a runtime of node v8 and hence tried by default to use node-oracledb as the driver. There were many challenges to establish the connections when a fork of node-oracledb --> oracledb-for-lambda was able to make this work between a function within AWS to a simple oracle DB within AWS.

However the code broke with following error when tried out with original environment where it connects to an on-premise Oracle 11g RAC cluster. Following is the error:

```
ORA-21561: OID generation failed
```

VPC[{AWS Node Lambda}] -> Direct Connect -> On prem n/w -> Oracle RAC Cluster

**Additional Notes:**
Added HOSTALIASES file for name resolution

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb-for-lambda');
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
'use strict';

str_host = os.hostname() + ' localhost\n';

fs.writeFileSync(process.env.HOSTALIASES,str_host , function(err){
    if(err) throw err;  
});

var connAttr = {
    user: "user",
    password: "pass",
    connectString: "connection string"
};
oracledb.getConnection(connAttr, function (err, connection) {

if (err) {
    log.error("Error Log>>>>>: " + err.message);
    return;
}
log.info('Connection was successful!' + connection);

connection.close(
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            log.error('Error while closing connection'+err.message);
            return;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177408/aws-python-lambda-with-oracle-oid-generation-failed-even-after-adding-hostalia?rq=1 The second answer mentions outbound DNS...

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201869/aws-python-lambda-with-oracle-oid-generation-failed

Comment: Also try using Node.js with Oracle Client 18c which had some improvements for OID generation to reduce the occurrence of similar errors.  An 18c Client will connection to Oracle Database 11.2 or greater.  Hopefully you're using ideas from node-oracledb-for-lambda and not node-oracledb-for-lambda itself, since the node-oracledb version is very old.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure the connection string which you have give is in below format

> //server-ip:port/database_name

Comment: may i know why this answer was down voted ? . I used this exact same code and connection string as mentioned above then connection was established.

Comment: The issue is not with the connection string itself but in domain name based lookup. Providing IP is not possible with RAC cluster as each cluster node picks its own IP.