# Run cleanup script on AWS Oracle RDS from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, aws-lambda

I'm using Apex to deploy lambda functions in AWS.  I need to write a lambda function which runs a cleanup script on an Oracle RDS in my AWS VPC.  Oracle has a very nice python library called cx_Oracle, but I'm having some problems using it in a Lambda function (running on Python 2.7).  My first step was to try to run the oracle-described test code as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import boto3
import boto3.ec2
import os
import cx_Oracle


def handle(event, context):
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@my.oracle.rds:1521/orcl')
    print(str(con.version))
    con.close()
```

When I try to run this piece of test code, I get the following response:

```
Unable to import module 'main': /var/task/cx_Oracle.so: invalid ELF header
```

Google has told me that this error is caused because the cx_Oracle library is *not* a complete oracle implementation for python, rather it requires the SQLPlus client to be pre-installed, and the cx_Oracle library references components installed as part of SQLPlus.

Obviously pre-installing SQLPlus might be difficult.
Apex has the

```
hooks {}
```

functionality which would allow me to pre-build things, but I'm having trouble finding documentation showing what happens to those artefacts and how that works.  In theory I could download the libraries into a nexus or an S3 bucket, and then in my hooks{} declaration, I could add them to the zip file.  I could then try to install them as part of the python script.  However, I have a few problems with this:

1. How are the 'built' artefacts accessed inside the lambda
   function?  Can they be?  Have I misunderstood this?
2. Does a python 2.7 lambda function have enough access rights to
   the operating system of the host container to be able to install a
   library?
3. If the answer to question 2 is no, is there another way to write
   a lambda function to run some SQL against an Oracle RDS instance?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734748/aws-python-lambda-with-oracle/37753311#37753311

Comment: Mark B - a quick read of the answer you've linked to shows that this solution requires manually building the lambda function zip file.  We don't want to do that because we want to use Apex to build our Lambda functions.  This means that we can source-control the actual lambda function source code file, rather than an opaque zip file

Comment: You have to build the dependencies on an Amazon Linux machine, there is no way around it due to the binary dependencies required. You can still have the function's source code in Git. You can still use Apex. I don't understand why you think this prevents you from using Apex or why you think using Apex somehow prevents you from including these dependencies.